# jenkins pipeline : sh mv with param not working

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline. It is working fine.

However I need to do `sh (script: "mv ${JSON_FILE} ${JSON_FILE}.processing")` in stage. This simple command cannot be done. I am getting `No such field found: field java.lang.String processing`.

How to solve it ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Error states your variable resolves to a string which has no member `.processing`.

Comment: Never saw an error like this when using the ${} to  inject a variables value into a string. In case the code shown is 100% identical to what is in your pipeline script I’d assume a bug in the pipeline groovy plugin. Are you using a rather old version or something from 2017/2018?